# Как пользоваться координатами в Canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Изучаю анимацию в tkinter и столкнулся с проблемами в анимации(а точнее с координатами).Что означает цифра 2 в квадратных скобках?

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width = 200, height = 200)
c.pack()

def motion():
    c.move(ball, 1, 0)
    if c.coords(ball)[2] < 200:
         pass
```

Comment: То же, что и всегда - обращение к третьему элементу в списке.

Comment: А что собственно означают элементы в списке этой функции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Метод coords](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.coords-method) возвращает координаты двух противоположных углов "ограничивающего прямоугольника" (bounding box) фигуры*, обычно левого верхнего и правого нижнего:

```
(x1, y1, x2, y2)  # x1, y1 - координаты левого верхнего угла; x2, y2 - правого нижнего
```

[image: Диаграмма]

Таким образом, элемент с индексом 2 - это координата x правого нижнего угла.

Условие `if c.coords(ball)[2] < 200:` означает: если объект правым краем не заходит за границу в 200 пикселей от левого края** (координата x правого края меньше 200), то выполнить что-то (в данном случае `pass` - ничего).

* Если фигура - отрезок, то эти координаты показывают начало и конец отрезка. Но эти координаты также является и координатами углов ограничивающего прямоугольника для отрезка.

** Не всегда пикселей и не всегда от края холста - масштаб может быть не 1 к 1, и начало координат может не совпадать с левым верхним углом холста

Comment: Я так понимаю что цифра индекса означает одну из сторон ограничивающего прямоугольника? К примеру, 1 - левый верхний угол, 2 - правый верхний, 3 -  левый нижний, 4 - правый нижний?

Comment: Условно это стороны: левая, верхняя, правая, нижняя. Но не 4 угла, этими координатами задано только два угла.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое