# Что означают координаты, передаваемые в create_oval?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
circle = canvas.create_oval((150, 100, 170, 120), fill='yellow')
```

что значат вот эти 4 координаты "150, 100, 170, 120"

Comment: Что написано в документации?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как пользоваться координатами в Canvas?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/941626/1365)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как пользоваться координатами в Canvas?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/941626/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-canvas)

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

неужто сюда написать проще, чем 1 минуту потратить на поиск такой простой темы?

https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/create_oval.html

Answer (score 2):

Это координаты двух противоположных углов "ограничивающего прямоугольника" (bounding box) фигуры (не обязательно овала, так же и любой другой фигуры), в который вписывается эта фигура. Обычно это координаты левого верхнего и правого нижнего углов:

```
(x1, y1, x2, y2)  # x1, y1 - координаты левого верхнего угла; x2, y2 - правого нижнего
```

[image: Диаграмма]