# Как поставить условие на координаты фигуры Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

У нас есть холст с геометрической фигурой - шар. С помощью функции `moving()` осуществляется её передвижение вниз окна. Как можно поставить условие на её координаты? То есть, как сказать, например: если фигура находится на координатах 500 и 410, то остановить функцию движения фигуры.

```
import tkinter
import time
window = tkinter.Tk()

#settings
window.title("Traffic lights")
window.geometry("800x1000+50+4")
window.configure(background="#545454")
window.resizable(width=False,height=False)

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window, bg='#038c75', height=1000, width=1000)
canvas.pack()
 
canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,800,1000,fill="white", outline="#633", width=1)

white_shell = canvas.create_oval((345, 55), (445, 155), fill='#D8D8D8',outline="#494949", width=8)
white_num = canvas.create_text(395,105, text="1",fill="#494949", font=("Open Sand Extra Bold", 65))
white = white_shell, white_num
def moving():
    canvas.move(white_shell,0,1)
    canvas.move(white_num,0,1)
    canvas.after(10, moving)

moving()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть вот [тут](https://younglinux.info/tkinter/canvasmeth)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/941626/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы узнать координаты объекта в Tkinter, нужно использовать метод `canvas.coords(obj)`. Он возвращает кортеж из 4 элементов:

(`x` левого верхнего угла, `y` левого верхнего угла, `x` правого нижнего угла, `y` правого нижнего угла)

Остаётся только использовать это любым подходящим способом.

Пример решения (функция `moving`):

```
def moving():
    coords = canvas.coords(white_shell)
    if coords[1] <= 410:
        canvas.move(white_shell, 0, 1)
        canvas.move(white_num, 0, 1)
        canvas.after(10, moving)
```

Comment: что означает ```coords[1]```? конкретно вопрос за что отвечает число в скобках

Comment: `coords` - кортеж. Число в квадратных скобках - это индекс элемента (нумерация с 0).

Comment: Почитайте подробнее про списки, так будет понятнее: https://pymanual.github.io/list.html . Кортеж устроен похоже.

Comment: @vkwi вот тут описано: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/941643/1365